# Movie where a kid reads a book and enters a fantasy world. School bullies try to steal the book

Tags: story-identification, movie

The main plot was about a kid who finds a book and when he reads it (at school) he enters a fantasy world where he meets a girl. When he first sees her, she's fixing something and they're in a field.

When he’d read all that stuff would happen in that world, I remember him trying to protect the book from bullies who were trying to get it. The girl helps him

It’s a 2000s movie (or even older?).

Comment: You said in a comment below that it's not The Neverending Story but your question describes the movie The Neverending Story (not any of its sequels) in every particular. Can you add some detail as to why you're so sure it's not that?

Answer (score 7):

The [Blurb](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0110647/?ref_=tt_urv) for the Neverending Story part III: Escape from Fantasia released in 1994, runs;

> A young boy must restore order when a group of bullies steal the magical book that acts as a portal between Earth and the imaginary world of Fantasia.

The whole Neverending Story series of films is about being drawn into the book world of Fantasia by reading. The line between figuratively and literally is blurred throughout the series. But Fantasia, the fantasy world is undoubtedly real in some way and the Hero travels there at some point in each of the films.

In a variation from the first two films, the bad guys in III are bullies from the real world. [TVTropes](https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Film/TheNeverendingStory?from=Film.TheNeverEndingStoryIIIEscapeFromFantasia) gives us this insight.

> Not-So-Harmless Villain: The Nasties are a group of typical High School Bullies who aren't exceptionally bright or clever, so you probably wouldn't expect them to be much of threat compared the Nothing or the Emptiness. Here's the thing though: unlike the former two, they are from the real world, and therefore have the ability to completely control or alter what occurs in the NeverEnding Story Book, thus ironically making them possibly the most dangerous villains in the whole series!

Comment: Thank you all so much but it’s not the neverending story.